# Managing magento categories

Tags: php, magento, sidebar

We can manage sidebar category listing  by using magento extensions.

How do you manage categories as per page layout in magento? 
Also can one manage the color or style for specifically sidebar categories?

What process is used for these extensions?

Comment: Sorry to say this...  I didnt even understand what you are saying and what you are asking for... Brief your question. So that it has to understand for other person in a single shot. Add some more details to it

Comment: Update your title Magneto?